# Iterate through dataframe, capturing substring and creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns. The one relevant for this problem is the group_email. From this group email I need to parse out a specific substring from it to get a group_code. I have created two different regex patterns to capture the substring based on the starting. If the email starts with "gcp" I want to follow one specific regex extract and create a group_code in the same row. Or if the email starts with "irm" follow a different regex pattern and do the same. Finally if the email doesn't start with either, just give null  as the group_code.

Here I have some logic for this process:

```
if(group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("gcp") is True):
        group_member_df['group_code'] = (group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'))
        
elif(group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith("irm") is True):
        group_member_df['group_code'] = (group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)'))
        
else:
        group_member_df['group_code'] = "null"
```

The first if, is checking if the string starts with "gcp", if that's true, i want to extract from the group_email and create the group_code from this. Same goes with the elif, just with "irm" and different pattern, finally else with null.

How can I modify this so go through each row in the dataframe and run this logic on it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [np.select()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to put all your conditions into one line.

```
condlist = [group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith('gcp'), group_member_df['group_email'].astype(str).str.startswith('irm')]

choicelist = [group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'), group_member_df['group_email'].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)')]

group_member_df['group_code'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, 'null')
```